# Autofilter range while in UserForm causes premature function exit without error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, execution, userform

Excel 15.0.4833.1001
Win 7 Pro 64 Bit

---

**Update:**

I have a proximate cause:
The data range being filtered is **also** the `RowSource` for a listbox on my `UserForm`. I modified the function to copy all the data to a temporary sheet and *then* do all the operations, and now it is working fine.

---

I have a `GetFileredDataRange` function which takes a `providerName`, filters a `rawDataRange` appropriately, and copies the filtered results to a new worksheet.

---

Function:

```
    Public Function GetFilteredDataRange(ByVal providerName As String) As Range
        '/ returns range containing filtered data

        Const PROVIDER_COLUMN As Long = 2

        Dim rawFinalrow As Long
        rawFinalrow = wsInputs.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        Dim rawFinalColumn As Long
        rawFinalColumn = wsInputs.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

        Dim rawDataRange As Range
        Set rawDataRange = wsInputs.Range(wsInputs.Cells(1, 1), wsInputs.Cells(rawFinalrow, rawFinalColumn))

        If wsInputs.AutoFilterMode And wsInputs.FilterMode Then wsInputs.ShowAllData

        If providerName <> "All" Then
            '/==========================================================
            '/============== Unexpected behaviour here (#1) ============
            '/==========================================================

            On Error GoTo cleanFail '/ causing unexpected exit when called from userform
                rawDataRange.AutoFilter Field:=PROVIDER_COLUMN, Criteria1:=providerName
            On Error GoTo 0

        End If

        wsFilteredInputs.Cells.ClearContents
        wsInputs.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy
        wsFilteredInputs.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        If wsInputs.AutoFilterMode Then wsInputs.Cells.AutoFilter
        Set GetFilteredDataRange = wsFilteredInputs.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

        Exit Function
cleanFail:
        Debug.Print "Error Triggered"
        Stop

    End Function
```

---

This function works perfectly when called like so from the immediate window:

```
GetFilteredDataRange "Aegon"
```

---

However, if I call this function from a `UserForm`, like so:

```
Private Sub ProviderSelectBox_Click() '/ (#2)

    Dim selectedName As String
    selectedName = "Aegon" '/ set manually for now while testing functionality

    Dim filteredDataRange As Range
    Set filteredDataRange = GetFilteredDataRange(selectedName)

    AccountSelectBox.RowSource = filteredDataRange.Address

End Sub
```

Then strange behaviour occurs. Specifically:

The code will run as expected to the problem line (#1).
Then, the range will be Auto-Filtered, **but** code execution will jump back to the calling procedure (#2) in the userform.
It will then run again and either repeat the same behaviour or eventually error because this line:

```
    If wsInputs.AutoFilterMode And wsInputs.FilterMode Then wsInputs.ShowAllData
```

doesn't trigger after the first time around. So it tries to `Autofilter` an already-filtered range.

Thoughts on what's causing this strange premature-exit-without-error behaviour and/or how to avoid it?

---

**Speculation:**

Something to do with userforms not relinquishing active-window focus until they're closed or deactivated.

---

Comment: I can't get a repro. I renamed `Sheet1` to `wsInputs`, `Sheet2` to `wsFilteredInputs`, typed "Provider", "Foo" and "Bar" in row 1, "Aegon", 12 and 42 in row 2, and "Aerys II", 32, and 44 in row 2; then I added a std module `Module1`, pasted your function there; then I added a form with a button that does `Debug.Print GetFilteredDataRange("Aegon").Address` and got an address in the debug output, both with and without breakpoints on the `On Error` line.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Hmmm. See update, I may have a better handle on the cause now.

Comment: What happens without your error handler?

Comment: @Absinthe It never got triggered in the first place.